# Add "supertag" to "subtag"

Tags: discussion, tags

"Pandas" is a data framework built onto "python". I asked a question that was very specific to a tiny part of pandas (panel analysis). It was very pandas specific, since it was about the logic on how sometimes data that I pull from the database is a read-only, but sometimes also permits a write operation (not completely the truth, simplified it).

So then, since this is of no relevance to anyone who has python knowledge but non in pandas, I intentionally only tagged it with `pandas`, not with `python`. However, an edit was approved where that tag was added.

I disagree, since it would imply to add *any* supertag that contains a subtag. While shouldn't also "programming", "OOP" etc. be added then, following the same logic?

The [question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756711/pandas-panel-copy-versus-view).

Answer (score 4):

Your slippery slope argument isn't very convincing. [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming) (which has been burninated for this very reason...) and [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop) tags are just useless for their broadness; a tag for the programming language typically isn't. Even in your case, keeping the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag could let people who choose to ignore Python not see your question instead of forcing them to also explicitly ignore a tag for every Python module under the sun.